# A function returns an address of a variable ... ends up being a different variable?

Tags: go

This code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)


type State struct { Foo string }
type Handler struct { state State }

func (handler Handler) State() *State { return &handler.state }

func main() {
   input := `{"Foo": "bar"}`
   handler := Handler{}
   state := handler.State()
   json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), state)


   fmt.Printf("%v\n", state)
   fmt.Printf("%v\n", handler.state)
}
```

Prints

```
&{bar}
{}
```

([see for yourself](https://play.golang.org/p/J4szhQGcfJo))

This buffles me: `handle.State()` returns the address of `handler.state`, 
so how is it possible that `state` (which is `&handler.state`) and `handler.state` end up containing different things (one is empty, the other is not)?

If I change `state := handler.State()` to `state := &handler.state`, then it works the way I expect it to.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method is taking the address of a field in the receiver argument `handler`.  A new `handler` value is created on every invocation of the function.

Use a pointer receiver to get the results you expect:

```
func (handler *Handler) State() *State { return &handler.state }
```

In this case, the function returns the address of the field in the caller's `handler`.